# python broken if else nested in for loop

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, counter

I am trying to run a loop with a counter in the code below.

```
import sys
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import email.header
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re
from lxml import etree, html
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "sample@gmail.com"
EMAIL_FOLDER = "INBOX"


def stringify_children(node):
    from lxml.etree import tostring
    from itertools import chain
    parts = ([node.text] +
            list(chain(*([c.text, tostring(c), c.tail] for c in node.getchildren()))) +
        [node.tail])
    # filter removes possible Nones in texts and tails
    return ''.join(filter(None, parts))

def process_mailbox(M):
    """
    Do something with emails messages in the folder.  
    For the sake of this example, print some headers.
    """

    rv, data = M.search(None, "ALL")
    if rv != 'OK':
        print "No messages found!"
        return
    for num in data[0].split(): 
        rv, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print "ERROR getting message", num
            return

        msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])

        if msg.is_multipart():
            html = None
            print "Checking for html or text"
            for part in msg.get_payload():
                if part.get_content_charset() is None:
                    charset = chardet.detect(srt(part))['encoding']
                else:
                    charset = part.get_content_charset()
                if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                    text = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
                    f = open('email.txt', 'w')
                    f.write(text)
                    f.close
                if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
                    html = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
                    f = open('email.html','w')
                    f.write(html)
                    f.close
                if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                    continue

                filename = part.get_filename()

                if not os.path.isfile(filename) :
                    fp = open(filename, 'wb')
                    fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                    fp.close()
                    return 0

            if html is None:
                return text.strip()
            else:
                return html.strip()


class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()





def parse_html():
    htmldoc = open('email.html', 'r+')
    doc = htmldoc.read()
    doc = re.sub('foobar', 'bar', doc)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("email.html"))
    VALID_TAGS = ['iframe', 'video', 'o>', 'li', 'sub', 'sup', 'source', 'br', 'h3', 'h4', 'h6', 'hr', 'q', 'mark','wbr', 'audio','strong', 'em', 'p','ul', 'li', 'br', 'blockquote', 'pre', 'del', 'h3', 'body', 'header', 'html', 'title', 'div', 'img', 'a']

    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name == 'i':
            tag.name = 'em'
        elif tag.name == 'cite':
            tag.name = 'em'
        elif tag.name == 'b':
            tag.name = 'strong'
        elif tag.name == 'kdb':
            tag.name = 'strong'
        elif tag.name == 'var':
            tag.name = 'strong'
        elif tag.name == 'aside':
            tag.name = 'blackquote'
        elif tag.name == 'code':
            tag.name = 'pre'
        elif tag.name == 'samp':
            tag.name = 'pre'
        elif tag.name == 's':
            tag.name = 'del'
        elif tag.name == 'h1':
            tag.name = 'h3'
        elif tag.name == 'h2':
            tag.name = 'h3'

    pretty_soup = soup.prettify()
    docstring = str(pretty_soup)
    tree = etree.fromstring(docstring)
    walkAll = tree.iterchildren() 

    count = 0
    for elt in walkAll:
        if count <= 300: 
            child = stringify_children(elt)
            childtext = strip_tags(child)
            childstring = childtext.replace(" ", "")
            for i in childstring:
                count = count + len(i)
                print count

        else:
            root = etree.Element("elt")
            root.text = ''
            root.tail = ''

    etroot = tree.getroottree()
    results = etree.tostring(etroot)
    htmldoc.write(results)





M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

try:
    rv, data = M.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, getpass.getpass())
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    print "LOGIN FAILED!!! "
    sys.exit(1)

print rv, data

rv, mailboxes = M.list()
if rv == 'OK':
    print "Mailboxes:"
    print mailboxes

rv, data = M.select(EMAIL_FOLDER)
if rv == 'OK':
    print "Processing mailbox...\n"
    process_mailbox(M)
    M.close()
    parse_html()
else:
    print "ERROR: Unable to open mailbox ", rv

M.logout()
```

But my loop below is broken and I don't understand why. When the count reaches 300, the code in the else statement should be executed but instead the counter continues to iterate through the elements.

I want the else statement to execute for each element after the count reaches 300. The results would affect the elements after 300 was reached and the elements iterated through before the count reaches 300 would not be affected. I put a print "test" in the else statement to test it and it's not getting printed.

the purpose of this code is to grab an email and count the text in the email, when the total text count reaches a certain parameter, in this case 300, else executes and cleans the text out of the remaining elements. I used 300 randomly. The text limit could also be 50.

```
count = 0
for elt in walkAll:
    if count <= 300: 
       child = stringify_children(elt)
       childtext = strip_tags(child)
       childstring = childtext.replace(" ", "")
           for i in childstring:
               count = count + len(i)
               print count

    else:
        root = etree.Element("elt")
        root.text = ''
        root.tail = ''
```

EDIT

I can insert an if break condition after count = count + len(i), which will stop the loop, like this:

```
count = 0
for elt in walkAll:
    if count <= 300: 
        child = stringify_children(elt)
        childtext = strip_tags(child)
        childstring = childtext.replace(" ", "")
        for i in childstring:
            count = count + len(i)
            if count >= 300:
                break
            print count

    else:
        root = etree.Element("elt")
        root.text = ''
        root.tail = ''
```

This breaks the counting but the else statement still doesn't run

Comment: As it sits on Stack Overflow, your indentation is incorrect. There should be an indent after the `if count <= 300:` line.

Comment: The `else` statement will be executed once for each element in `walkAll` as soon as `count` has reached `300` in the previous iteration - is that not what you want?

Comment: FYI, I had to add pretty_soup = soup.prettify().encode('utf8') to get your code to work for me.

Comment: I want the else statement to execute for each element after the count reaches 300. The results would affect the elements after 300 was reached and the elements iterated through before the count reaches 300 would not be affected. I put a print "test" in the else statement to test it and it's not getting printed.

Comment: @DanielKane what value does count get to when you run the code?

Comment: It's counting every text space in the string so it starts at a value of 0 and counts incrementally up to 551 currently. The total it counts will vary depending on the original email it pulls from but that's the current count I am getting.

Comment: @DanielKane I  was just asking as logging in to my email it never goes above 169.Can you put a few comments in your code in the troublesome part and indent it correctly.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham comments and indents added to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand exactly you want to do but based on your code above this should work.

```
for elt in walkAll:
    count = 0
    child = stringify_children(elt)
    childtext = strip_tags(child)
    childstring = childtext.replace(" ", "")
    for s in childstring:
        count+=1
        if count >= 300:
            root = etree.Element("elt")
            root.text = ''
            root.tail = ''
```